# Android ProgressDialog takes time to appear on screen

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have attached on click listener to a text view, inside on click listener a function say f1 is called and inside f1 another function say f2 is called.

Inside f2 I have created a android ProgressDialog object using current activity context, and called show function on progressDialog object. ProgressDialog takes time to appear on screen around 5-6 sec.

I have analyzed my code, but not able to understand why it takes this much time ?

```
  textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                ShowSyncDialog(); - f1
       }
   });

   public void ShowSyncDialog()
   {
       fnSyncOfflineData(); - f2
    }

   public void fnSyncOfflineData()
   { 
       ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
       progressDialog.show();

      //other code 
   }
```

Comment: Add some code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You should call your functions in an `AsyncTask`. Also `ProgressDialog` must be shown at the beginning of this works. Use something like this:

```
public class YourTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private Context mContext;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public YourTask(Context context) {
        super();
        mContext = context;
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Your Message");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... values) {
        // If you want to use 'values' string in here
        String values = values[0];

        String yourResult = yourFunction();

        return yourResult;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        // Your task has done
        ...
    }
}
```

Then call this task with:

```
new YourTask(YourActivity.this).execute();
```

You can change return type of task `doInBackground` method. This is just an example, you can search about `AsyncTask`.

Good luck.

Comment: but I am displaying ProgressDialog before starting any tasks, so why does it takes time. fnSyncOfflineData is just a simple function without any Web API calls or other tasks which takes time.

Comment: I know but this is how Android system works. You are in a single thread. You called progressDialog.show() before your function is called. Then your function could lock this single thread when the dialog has not yet shown.

Comment: but in single thread also execution is step by step so once progressDialog.show() is called it must be executed first . I have written log before and after progressDialog.show() log get printed but progress dialog takes time to appear

Comment: Try to use `AsyncTask` and see the difference.